# How to set url encoding scheme for form data in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Mikeal's request module for making a `POST` request. My `POST` request looks like this:

```
request.post({url, form: {'data': req.body.data}}, function(error, response, body) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  return res.status(response.statusCode).send(body);
}});
```

When I try to decode the url encoded payload, I get something like this,

```
data[0][docType]=style_basic_info&data[0][styleId]=yolo&data[0][baseProduct]=AILP&data[0][baseColor]=Navy blue&data[0][vendorArticleNumber]=&data[0][vendorArticleName]=&data[0][brand]=Nautica&data[0][ageGroup]=14-20 yrs
```

which is in array bracket notation, but the server expects this format on url decoding,

```
data=[{"docType":"style_basic_info","styleId":"yolo","baseProduct":"AILP","baseColor":"Navy blue","vendorArticleNumber":null,"vendorArticleName":null,"brand":"Nautica","ageGroup":"14-20 yrs"}]
```

How can I change the URL encoding method so that on decoding I get result in the above form? 
I went through the documentation, but couldn't find anything on this.

Comment: Looks like that server is expecting JSON - which is unusual for a `<form>`, but can be trivially made using `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Yes, you are right, currently am doing it through express's http. But it's not clean at all, I am looking for a way achieve this through request package.